# Integrating AppSheet, PostgreSQL, and MinIO S3 Server for Photo Storage

Tags: postgresql, integration, minio, google-appsheet

I am developing a student management system using AppSheet and PostgreSQL. In my PostgreSQL "students" table, there's a "photo" column that should store photos in our MinIO S3 server. However, when a photo is uploaded via AppSheet, it gets stored in Google Drive.

I expected AppSheet to store the photos directly to MinIO S3 since the "students" table is connected to it, but it seems I can't find a setting or feature to alter the storage destination within AppSheet.

Could anyone guide me or suggest how to store AppSheet-uploaded photos directly to MinIO S3, given PostgreSQL is part of the stack? Any experiences, alternative solutions, or workarounds are welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help.